# Activity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragment, swipe

I am trying to change my App which has a bunch of single Activities into a swipe tab app.
i want 3 activities in the swipe tabs. I used the google example wich eclipse created for me. I don't seem to get the correct way of doing that.

I have the following (relevant) code (the other stuff is in eclipse, it's too much to post here):

Main.class which is called at launch (the last inner class of it):

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {


public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        // public DummySectionFragment() {
        // }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

activity_fragment.xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:name="com.mikebdev.refuel.MainActivity"
    class="com.mikebdev.refuel.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/stats"
    android:name="com.mikebdev.refuel.Statistics"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/refuel"
    android:name="com.mikebdev.refuel.ReFuel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" />
```

The Activities all extend `FragmentActivity` from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

now when starting my app, i get the following error:

```
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at com.mikebdev.refuel.Main$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(Main.java:184)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1011)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1374)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mikebdev.refuel.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
04-27 12:08:11.244: E/AndroidRuntime(28728):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i was able to solve everything by adding a switch case statement here:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

            Fragment fragment;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new StatisticsFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new MainActivityFragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new DbListViewFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment  = new DummySectionFragment();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }
```

and I made a copy of my activities and converted those to fragments like explained on this video:

[Converting An Activity To A Fragment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGXenxtDEGQ)

now everything seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have nested fragments embedded in a xml layout file. You'll have to add them at runtime.

Edit: There are countless tutorials on implementing swipeable tabs with fragments please look at them, many are self explanatory. The main points are:

- create a layout file which will contain the tabs and the `ViewPager`
- create the fragments that will be used as the tabs/pages in the `ViewPager`
- create a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and assign it to the `ViewPager`
- bind the tabs selection to the `ViewPager` pages.

You could use the `ViewPager` directly in the `Activity` or you could use a wrapper `Fragment`, the difference is that you'll need to pass `getChildFragmentManager()` to the `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: okay, cool, i failed to mention that this fragment stuff is some kind of a riddle to me. Can you explain this a little more? thanks :)

Comment: I really have a hard time understanding this stuff so please accept my apologies. I've been reading about this stuff for hours now and what i've come up with is a switch case statement in the `public Fragment getItem` Method and i created a inner fragment class in my `FragmentActivity`. Now i can see the different layouts in the tabs but how can i link the Fragments with the `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: @mike.b93 The `Fragment` that will be placed in the `Activity` will hold the `ViewPager`. In that fragment you'll set the `ViewPager`'s adapter as a `FragmentPagerAdapter` passing it `getChildFragmentManager()`. *Now i can see the different layouts in the tabs but how can i link the Fragments with the FragmentActivity* - so do you see the content of the nested fragment? I don't understand what you understand by "link the Fragments with the FragmentActivity".

Comment: In the Tab i just see the layout, because the inner fragment class just shows a layout. But all the code is in the `FragmentActivity` class. So there is nothing but the layout showing.

I'll start reading about the `ViewPager` stuff you wrote

Comment: i answered my own question. Thank you for your time. You helped me a lot